# IAR embedded workbench MSP430 interrupt simulation rejected

Tags: c, embedded, microcontroller, msp430, iar

I've a question.
Does anybody know why my interrupt is rejected when I'm simulating?

I simulate the SYSNMI_VECTOR, I've enabled the SVMLIE and SVMHIE bit.
But when I look in the interrupt log my interrupts are rejected.

As initialization I do this:

```
  //Unlock PMM settings
  PMMCTL0_H=PMMPW_H;
  //Set control
  SVSMHCTL=SVMHE|SVSMHRRL_7|SVMHFP;
  SVSMLCTL=SVMLE|SVSMLRRL_7|SVMLFP;

  //clear interrupt flags
  PMMIFG&= ~(SVMLIFG|SVMHIFG);

  //setup interrupts
  PMMRIE|= SVMLIE|SVMHIE;

  //Disable PMM settings
  PMMCTL0_H = 0x00;
```

And this is my interrupt

```
#pragma vector=SYSNMI_VECTOR
__interrupt void NMI_interrupt(void) {
//Breakpoint here
}
```

I hope someone can help me with this.

Comment: Probably the debugger disables interrupt during single step etc? The key to successful embedded programming is otherwise to never use simulators and always program on-chip.

Comment: Thank you for your comment probably this is the best way of working. I just would like to do this for some quick test.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "rejected"? What happens when you set SVML/HIFG manually?

Comment: My interrupt log shows the interrupt is rejected. I'll try to set it manually

Comment: Thanks for the help. I decided to simulate things manually and don't use the IDE for that.